# NGINX Set client_max_body_size For One Route on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, node.js, elastic-beanstalk

I have a Node.Js application deployed to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. When uploading a file, I get the following error:

```
2019/03/04 17:00:42 [error] 4325#0: *722 client intended to send too large body: 30877841 bytes,
client: my ip,
server: ,
request: "POST /api/files/upload HTTP/1.1",
host: "mydomain.com",
referrer: "mydomain.com/..."
```

Therefore, I need to add `client_max_body_size XXM` to `nginx.conf`.

**Issues**

(1) But as I am using Amazon **Elastic Beanstalk**, I don't know how to do this, without connecting to every single EC2 instance and updating the file manually.

(2) I also want to increase the max size only for **one url**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [customize the software on a Linux Elastic Beanstalk instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) using environment configuration files. For your specific case, in your local application home folder, you should have a .ebextensions directory. In that folder create a new file, let's call it "nginx.config", and place the following into that file:

```
---
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_client_max_body_size.conf:
    content: "client_max_body_size 10m;"
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
```

This instructs Elastic Beanstalk to create a file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ called 00_client_max_body_size.conf, and to place a single line in this file containing:

```
client_max_body_size 10m;
```

Bundle up your application and upload a new version to Elastic Beanstalk. Once you have done this, you will notice the following on your Linux instance:

```
$ ls -al     /etc/nginx/conf.d
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  8 00:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 15 22:24 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   25 Mar  8 00:34 00_client_max_body_size.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1351 Mar  8 00:35 00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  283 Dec 13 00:21 virtual.conf
```

This will get included by the main `nginx.conf` file that is present on all nodejs elastic beanstalk environments, as this file has a line at the end of its http block as follows:

```
http {

...

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
# End Modification
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation with a Docker deployment into Elastic Beanstalk. I was able to solve it with an added config file here: `<app>/.ebextensions/increase_upload_size.config` with the following code:

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"

files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 20M;
```

The change was implemented when I did an "Upload and Deploy" within EB.